# how to obtain the transaction begin time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How to obtain the transaction begin time in Oracle? Is there such a built-in function to be used in queries?

More specifically, I need a function, let's call it `trans_begin_time()`, to be used in this way:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET batch_update_time = trans_begin_time()
WHERE some_criteria
```

Such a function, if exists, would help me in two ways:

first, I can update all the records  with the same date value - please note `sysdate` won't work as this is very a large table and `sysdate` would give varying values.

Second, I would be able to use it anywhere without the need to store `sysdate` value beforehand and then use it in the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
11:43:20 SYSTEM@sandbox> create table test as select * from dual;         

Table created.                                                                 

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04                                                           
11:43:26 SYSTEM@sandbox> set transaction read write name 'test';          

Transaction set.                                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                                           
11:43:35 SYSTEM@sandbox> insert into test values (1);                     

1 row created.                                                                 

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                                           
11:43:42 SYSTEM@sandbox> select name, start_time from v$transaction;      

NAME       START_TIME                                                          
---------- --------------------                                                
test       10/12/12 11:43:34                                                   

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01                                                           
11:43:47 SYSTEM@sandbox> commit;                                          

Commit complete.                                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01                                                           
11:44:00 SYSTEM@sandbox> select name, start_time from v$transaction;      

no rows selected                                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                                           
11:44:02 SYSTEM@sandbox>
```

Or, for each session:

```
11:59:15 SYSTEM@Sandbox> set transaction name 'test_by_addr';                           

Transaction set.                                                                             

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                                                         
11:59:18 SYSTEM@Sandbox> insert into test values(1);                                    

1 row created.                                                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                                                         
11:59:21 SYSTEM@Sandbox> get xact                                                       
  1  select s.sid                                                                            
  2        ,s.serial#                                                                        
  3        ,s.username                                                                       
  4        ,s.status                                                                         
  5        ,t.name                                                                           
  6        ,t.start_time                                                                     
  7* from v$transaction t join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr                               
11:59:27 SYSTEM@Sandbox> /                                                              

       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME                       STATUS   NAME       START_TIME          
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ -------- ---------- --------------------
        39       1015 SYSTEM                         ACTIVE   test_by_ad 10/12/12 11:59:17   
                                                              dr                             


Elapsed: 00:00:00.01                                                                         
11:59:30 SYSTEM@Sandbox> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') from dual;                 

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')                                                                 
----------------------------
39                                                                                           

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is a function to call in my query. I have edited my post for more clarification.

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi why don't you just manually set a variable to `sysdate` somewhere in your code, where the transaction actually begins, and then use it wherever you need?

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi and, in fact, what high-level task are you solving by this? logging some "last updated" time?

Comment: My table is large, and I want all those records that are updated in one batch, get the same value. `sysdate` wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi `declare myTime date := sysdate; begin update MYTABLE set batch_update_time = myTime where blah-blah; commit; end;` why doesn't it? just fix your value, don't put `sysdate` in queries explicitly.

Comment: This works yes; but I would much prefer to do all the work in a single `SQL` statement instead of a block, IF possible.

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi how do you invoke your updates? plsql, java? any reason for not passing pre-defined date constant in query using bind variables, e.g., `update mytable set batch_update_time = :myTime where foo=bar`? I do believe that passing a predefined constant date to a query is way more simple (and obvious) solution than figuring out transaction start date/time at runtime.

Comment: Please read my updated post, as to the reasons. Now, this is what I wanted to know? Doesn't exist such a function? Then, yes, I won't have any other choices. I HAVE TO adhere to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that will return the same date for a single session.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg AS
  2     FUNCTION get_session_date RETURN DATE;
  3  END;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg AS
  2     g_date DATE;
  3     FUNCTION get_session_date RETURN DATE IS BEGIN RETURN g_date; END;
  4  BEGIN
  5     g_date := SYSDATE;
  6  END;
  7  /

Package body created.

SQL> SELECT to_char(pkg.get_session_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(PKG.GET_SES
-------------------
12/10/2012 10:07:32

SQL> EXEC dbms_lock.sleep(10);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT to_char(pkg.get_session_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(PKG.GET_SES
-------------------
12/10/2012 10:07:32
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is what I wanted. A question, though. Does this work if I change to auto-commit?

Comment: The date will only reset on new session: disconnect and reconnect. It will not reset on commit (so it is functionally different from @beherenow 's solution).

Comment: you can wrap `g_date := SYSDATE;` into a procedure and make it public, thus becoming able to reset g_date at an arbitrary moment of time

Comment: @Vincent So, during a session which may span multiple transactions, it won't work?

Comment: @be Wrapping the `sysdate` in a function won't help because the values would be re-calculated with each function call.

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi i didn't say "function". i said "procedure". current solution sets g_date to sysdate at first get_session_date invocation in each session, and you're not able to change it. if you wrap that assignment in a proc in the same package you'd be able to set new sysdate value when you need (i.e. when you start a new transaction in the same session) without reconnecting.

Comment: Yes, you said procedure; But I doubt it would make a difference as it would be your solution then. Thanks.